# tf.random_crop cannot be used with wildcards?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building a image translation network with Python3.5+TensorFlow1.8.
For data augmentation, I tried to use `tf.random_crop()` with wildcards like bellow:

```
# input images
A = tf.placeholder(tf.float, shape=(None, 480, 640, 3))
B = tf.placeholder(tf.float, shape=(None, 480, 640, 3))

# images concatenation to crop on the same random seed
AB = tf.concat([A, B], 3)

# random cropping with wildcard for batch_size specification
AB_cropped = tf.random_crop(AB, [-1, 480, 480, 4])

# cropped images
A_ = AB_cropped[:,:,:,:3]
B_ = AB_cropped[:,:,:,3:]

...
```

It doesn't work with some different errors for each run (sometimes works with the wrong result).
Occurred Errors are like bellow:

## InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected begin[0] in [0, 1], but got 2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1329, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
     [[Node: preprocess/random_crop = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](preprocess/concat, preprocess/random_crop/mod, preprocess/random_crop/size)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alpha_gan_based.py", line 247, in <module>
    _, eg_loss = sess.run([hybrid_op, hybrid_loss], {image:image_batch, depth:depth_batch, z_prior:sample_z()})
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1128, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1344, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1363, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
     [[Node: preprocess/random_crop = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](preprocess/concat, preprocess/random_crop/mod, preprocess/random_crop/size)]]

Caused by op 'preprocess/random_crop', defined at:
  File "alpha_gan_based.py", line 156, in <module>
    cropped = (tf.random_crop(merged, [-1, 192, 192, 4]) / 255) * 2 - 1
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 316, in random_crop
    return array_ops.slice(value, offset, size, name=name)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 625, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4687, in _slice
    "Slice", input=input, begin=begin, size=size, name=name)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected begin[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
     [[Node: preprocess/random_crop = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](preprocess/concat, preprocess/random_crop/mod, preprocess/random_crop/size)]]
```

## Reshape cannot infer the missing input size for an empty tensor unless all specified input sizes are non-zero

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_call
         return fn(*args)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1329, in _run_fn
         status, run_metadata)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
         c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
     tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Reshape cannot infer the missing input size for an empty tensor unless all specified input sizes are non-zero
         [[Node: encoder/flatten/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](encoder/Relu_6, encoder/flatten/Reshape/shape)]]

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "alpha_gan_based.py", line 248, in <module>
         _, eg_loss = sess.run([hybrid_op, hybrid_loss], {image:image_batch, depth:depth_batch, z_prior:sample_z()})
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
         run_metadata_ptr)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1128, in _run
         feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1344, in _do_run
         options, run_metadata)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1363, in _do_call
         raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
     tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Reshape cannot infer the missing input size for an empty tensor unless all specified input sizes are non-zero
         [[Node: encoder/flatten/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](encoder/Relu_6, encoder/flatten/Reshape/shape)]]

     Caused by op 'encoder/flatten/Reshape', defined at:
       File "alpha_gan_based.py", line 163, in <module>
         z_encoded, intermidiate = encoder(x_real_image)
       File "alpha_gan_based.py", line 54, in encoder
         x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 414, in flatten
         return layer.apply(inputs)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 762, in apply
         return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 652, in __call__
         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 376, in call
         outputs = array_ops.reshape(inputs, (array_ops.shape(inputs)[0], -1))
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3997, in reshape
         "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
         op_def=op_def)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
         op_def=op_def)
       File "/usr/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
         self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

     InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Reshape cannot infer the missing input size for an empty tensor unless all specified input sizes are non-zero
         [[Node: encoder/flatten/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](encoder/Relu_6, encoder/flatten/Reshape/shape)]]
```

If I specify `batch_size` instead of wildcards, it works without the errors.
This may not be critical problem for me because image translation networks generally work well with `batch_size=1`. 
However, I concern about the lack of `batch_size` flexibility.

Is it an unavoidable problem?
Or there is the other method for specifying wildcards?

Note:
Some articles about same errors with not relating `tf.random_crop` are seen.
They say "it is GPU lack problem!", it is sadly unavoidable problem for me... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`random_crop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_crop) doesn't work with wildcards. Instead of using -1 as the unknown dimension, you can do:

`AB_cropped = tf.random_crop(AB, [tf.shape(AB)[0], 480, 480, 4])`

Note that `tf.shape` gives the dynamic shape, which is fully known at runtime.